# Intent.ACTION_SEND to share text worked well before, but failed now

Tags: android, action, share, send

I used the same code below to share text to Line, Wechat,...
It worked well before, but now it transfers nothing to the other apps. Though I trace to see everything going the same and correctly  in the sendIntent(below). Does anyone have similar experiences?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

---

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)  .setAction("Action", null).show();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText()); //EditText..getText() is Editable, still can get string
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");              
          sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject here");
          sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, voiceTextView.getText());
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Sharing Option"));

     }
});
```

Comment: Great! It really works, though I don't know why right now. I will study the details. You save me a lot of time. Thank you!